# Delphi XE5 SHA1 Base64 Result not as expected

Tags: delphi

I am working on an interface to a system which requires a password digest. I have a Python script which produce the correct password digest but when I try the same thing in Delphi it comes up with a completely different result.

The values I am testing with are:

NONCE = 299770410

CREATED = 2015-09-07T11:34:50Z

PASSWORD = Stentrd94*

The password Digest = Base64(SHA-1(Nonce + Created + SHA-1(Password)))

Python Result = azFZeikCSbUvpiUx1tJI0foac24=

Delphi Code

```
TIdEncoderMIME.EncodeString(EncryptSHA1(NONCE+CREATED+EncryptSHA1(PASSWORD)));
```

Result of Delphi =  VTNoN08xOVdFcGM2S1RGb3B6SlBHV0FMN3BvPQ==

I know the TIdEncoderMIME.EncodeString part is working because a second part of the request is Base64(NONCE) which

```
python = Mjk5NzcwNDEw 
Delphi = Mjk5NzcwNDEw
```

so it appears to be something to do with EncryptSHA1 that is causing the problem. This is the EncryptSHA1 function

```
function EncryptSHA1(const aPassword : string) : string;
begin
Result := '';
if aPassword <> '' then // make sure we have a file to hash
  begin with TIdHashSHA1.Create do
    try
      Result := TIdEncoderMIME.EncodeBytes(HashString(aPassword));
//      Result := HashStringAsHex(aPassword);
    finally
      Free;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

The system that I am trying to communicate with is Royal Mail DMO if that helps. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

I have just broken down the Python Code and the

```
sha.new(PASSWORD).Digest() gives the following :  ■§Û→∟ÙM,┌åÓcÿ♥☻├.D¡d
```

and the SHA of password Digest gives :  k1Yz)☻IÁ/ª%1ÍÊHÐ·→sn.

This is then Base64.b64Encode which give the correct result. But I can not see how to achieve this with Delphi Indy.

Comment: The encoding of your password string is most likely the problem. String is by default a `UnicodeString`. You might want to try with a `Utf8String` or `AnsiString` depending on the Encoding you need.

Comment: Yeah, you need to be explicit about how you encode the text as binary. You've not done that. You need to decide on an encoding for your text. Pick the encoding that matches what the Python code uses.

Comment: Yes I understand what you are saying but I have tried lots of variations but none have worked. I have just updated the question to show some results of SHA1 in python which appear to be ascii and then Base64 encoded.

Comment: If you understand what we are saying, then please tell us how the text is to be encoded, and explain why your Delphi code does not explicitly enforce that encoding. A question edit with the missing detail is required.

Comment: You mention ASCII in a comment, but since ASCII is not a Unicode encoding, you'll encounter problems when your input uses characters outside the limited ASCII set. Are you sure you want to restrict passwords to ASCII?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in your EncryptSHA1 procedure. You return encoded string (TIdEncoderMIME.EncodeBytes) which is wrong.

Here is a procedure which gives correct output

```
var
  bPassword, bStr: TIdBytes;
  shaHash: TIdHashSHA1;
begin
  shaHash:=TIdHashSHA1.Create;
  try
    bPassword:=shaHash.HashBytes(ToBytes('Stentrd94*'));
    bStr:=ToBytes('299770410'+'2015-09-07T11:34:50Z');
    AppendBytes(bStr, bPassword);

    ShowMessage(TIdEncoderMIME.EncodeBytes(shaHash.HashBytes(bStr)));
  finally
    shaHash.Free
  end;
end;
```

You can use additional parameter to specify encoding

```
ToBytes('Stentrd94*', IndyTextEncoding_UTF8)
```

Comment: smooty86, Genius, that has got it nailed. Thank you so much, and thank to the other guys as well for your assistance.